# Retrieve multiple rows using CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I have following result for the query `select * from student where courseName = 'Science';`

Results:

```
student_id | name   | points | course_name   | course_id |
+----------+--------+--------+---------------+-----------+
       1107| Matt   |   3000 |     Science  |    10     |
|      1108| Charley|  12348 |     Science       |    20     |

2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Java interface which implements CrudReposity :

```
public interface StudentDetailsRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentDetails, Long> {

  List<StudentDetails> findByCourseName(String courseName);
  List<StudentDetails> findAll();
}
```

Implementation :

```
public class StudentController {

  @Autowired
  StudentDetailsRepository studentDetailsRepository;
.............

    List<StudentDetails> studentDetails =
        studentDetailsRepository.findByCourseName(
            Request.getCourseName());
    for (int i = 0; i < studentDetails.size(); i++) {
      logger.info("entries: " + studentDetails.get(i).getName());
    }

    return request;
  }
}
```

In the above code, I am getting the results

> entries: Matt, entries : Matt

StudentsDetails.java:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity(name = "com.StudentDetails")
public class StudentDetails extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

  private long studentId;
  private String name;
  private long points;
  private String courseName;
  private long courseId;

  public StudentDetails() {

  }

  public StudentDetails(long studentId, String name, long points, String courseName, long courseId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.courseId = courseId;
  }

  public long getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public long getPoints() {
    return points;
  }

  public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
  }

  public long getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
  }
}
```

The real problem is, it is showing size as 2 but only taking 1st row which is displaying twice. Not taking the second one. Please help me to take corresponding multiple rows from database table using CrudRepository.

Comment: post your `StudentDetails` class

Comment: added StudentDetails class in the question.

Comment: Are you sure its the same code as you are testing? because its missing braces here `studentDetailsRepository.findByCourseId(
            Request.getCourseId();` and won't even compile, which makes me think its not the actual code you are testing.

Comment: Your `courseId` is a `long` not a `String`...

Comment: @Pradeep actually this is a example for the model that I have created. real code is something else.

Comment: @Futuregeek StudentDetails class extends from AbstractPersistable that means that the id property for StudentDetails entity is defined because it is inhereted, but why I don't see the id field at your sql output?

Comment: I have created above mentioned mysql table without id field. but after building the application, I could see that in the table - that was assigned as 0. I have given auto increment to it. Now my code is working. Thanks @DanielC.

Answer (score 3):

StudentsDetails.java Should have an identifier.
Add @javax.persistence.Id on studentId;

`@Id`
`private long studentId;`

Also
`List<StudentDetails> findByCourseId(String courseId);`
 should be 
   `List<StudentDetails> findByCourseId(Long courseId);`

Comment: By giving @Id, I am getting error like "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: StudentDetailsDetailsRepository : Error creating bean with name 'StudentDetailsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.StudentDetails] does not define an Id

Comment: I edited my answer. @Id should be on primary key. I don't know, in your case, which is primary. It must be studentId.

Comment: The issue still exists. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:

Comment: @atulranjan Actually the id value is defined because the StudentDetails class extends from AbstractPersistable https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.html

Comment: Yes, if you extend AbstractPersistable then it overrides equal and hashcode methods using the field id `@Id @GeneratedValue private PK id;` . But, in your case u are assuming the id is studentId and jpa considers both of row equal. That is the reason your method returns duplicate rows. So, You need to remove AbstractPersistable and you can make the studentId field as @Id.